# Karate HTTP requests listener

Tags: http, listener, karate

Is there any way to listen to incoming requests during Karate test?

I saw that there is the [Async](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#async) option, but there it talks about Queues listeners only.

Is there anything similar, but for HTTP requests?

Answer (score 1):

First, this is a rare use-case, so there is not much support for it.

You can try using a [`RuntimeHook`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.2.1.RC1/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/RuntimeHook.java), it has a `beforeHttpCall()` handler.

Also refer the new API that allows you to inspect an HTTP response "after the fact": https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1962

Finally, if you really have some exotic use-case, refer this: https://twitter.com/getkarate/status/1417023536082812935