# Get the Failing URL from a Karate API Test

Tags: java, karate

I'm running Karate tests from Java runner with Gradle.
For monitoring purpose, I want to get the endpoint which is failing

For example, with this feature file:

```
Feature: health check

Scenario: Test endpoint which would almost always be successful
  Given url "https://google.com"
  Given path "/"
  When method get
  Then status 200

  Given path "/search"
  When method get
  Then status 500         # the test will fail here

  Given url "https://bing.com"
  When method get
  Then status 200
```

I want to get `google.com/search`; just `google.com` is fine, too.

I'm thinking of doing a linear search in the karate scenario results:

```java
Results results = Runner.path(// ...)

// get the failing step
int failingStep = results.getScenarioResults().get(x).failedStep.step.index

// get the failing URL by looking at the 'results.getScenarioResults().get(x).stepResults',
// from the first step until the 'failingStep'
```

Is there a more proper way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Karate is not really designed for this. So I don't have any better suggestions other than looping over the results like you are doing.

That said, I wanted to remind you that loops are possible. And the loop will continue even if one fails. Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54108755/143475

```
Feature:

Scenario Outline:
* url urlBase
* method get
* status 200

Examples:
| urlBase                   | 
| https://google.com        |
| https://google.com/search |
| https://bing.com          |
```

Maybe you can figure out some better ways.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation! Sure, I'll think of some other ways for the loop case

Comment: @SalvianReynaldi note that you can plug in an interceptor - that may give you some other ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73569836/143475